# How to ask ElasticSearch ignore properties which are not defined in the index mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create an index in ElasticSearch with a mapping in which I set `dynamic` to `strict`.

Before pushing data into ElasticSearch, I have to pick properties from a bigger JSON object to make the data satisfy the mapping, and sometimes it's nested. Otherwise, ElasticSearch will throw an error.

I know there is a property named `ignore_malformed`, but it'll suppress the exception and accept the data partially. I still need ElasticSearch to throw me an error if there are some data that have incorrect format type, I only need it to ignore properties not in the mapping object.

Comment: Why not simply setting `ignore_malformed` to false?  That way you're guaranteed to get an error if the value doesn't match the format declared in your mapping. And with `dynamic: strict` you're protected against creating new fields not in your mapping.

Comment: ^ this is correct